# Double Summation Simplifcation in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to simplify the sum

```
smp.Sum(smp.Sum(smp.Indexed('x',i), (i, 0, n)),(j,0,n))
```

where x, i, j, and n are standard defined sympy variables. Note that this is a double sum, but the variable being summed over (x_i) only depends on i. Hence, when simplifying this expression, I should get n*sum_i x_i but this is not the case. In other words

```
smp.Sum(smp.Sum(smp.Indexed('x',i), (i, 0, n)),(j,0,n)).simplify()
```

Does not remove the outer sum (over j) and replace it with a multiplicative factor of n, like it should.

Am I using simplification wrong here? Or is this not implemented in sympy yet...?

Comment: In general, to simplify sums, you also need to call `.doit()`. E.g. `Sum(Sum(i, (i, 0, n)), (j, 0, n)).doit().simplify()` gives `n*(n + 1)**2/2`.  But this doesn't seem to help for the indexed expression.

Comment: Indeed, `doit()` does not seem to solve the problem...